# http payload logging on JBoss AS 7

Tags: http, logging, jboss, jboss7.x, payload

Can anyone tell my how to enable logging of HTTP request and responce payloads on JBoss AS 7? I've found many tutorials, but none for the version 7.

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by the word 'payload' ?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://community.jboss.org/thread/201861

Comment: that link doesn't show how to display request/response *bodies*